# jQTouch pageAnimationStart Fires Twice

Tags: jquery, bind, jqtouch

For some reason when I use jQTouch pageAnimationStart, it gets fired twice.

Example:

```
$(this).bind('pageAnimationStart', function(e,info) {
    alert('Animation Started');
});
```

The alert is called twice.  Any ideas?

The workaround I created seems to work and is as follows:

```
var animation_start_count = 0;

$(document).bind('pageAnimationStart', function(e,info) {
    animation_start_count ++;

    if (animation_start_count == 1) {
        alert('Animation Started');
    }
    else {
        animation_start_count = 0;
    }
});
```

In my workaround, the alert is only called once.

I'm only creating the jQT object once.  Small nuisance but I wanted to know if anyone else ran into this issue. Same results with pageAnimationEnd as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think there are two `pageAnimationStart` events because two pages are being animated: the `toPage` and the `fromPage`. The same goes for `pageAnimationEnd`.

It's all in the doNavigation method in jqtouch.js.